# Neighbor of a terminal node in Networkx

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

I'm trying to obtain the neighbor nodes of a terminal node in Networkx

```
import networkx as nx

tail = [1,2,3]
head = [2,3,4]
ed_ls = [(t, h) for t, h in zip(tail, head)]
G = nx.OrderedDiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(ed_ls)

print(G[4])
print(G.in_edges(nbunch=[4]))
```

I'm not sure why am empty dict is returned.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`G[4]` returns an empty dictionary as there is no outgoing edge from the node. Whereas, `G.in_edges(nbunch=[4])` returns `(3, 4)` which is the edge which contains the node `4`.

If I understand correctly, you specifically want to access the neighbours of a terminal node ? Now in that case, the neighbours of the terminal node are simply the predecessors of the node (as there no successors to the node), you can simply try the function [Digraph.predecessors](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.predecessors.html#networkx.DiGraph.predecessors):

```
print(list(G.predecessors(4)))
# Output : [3]
```

Consider another example with more edges:

```
import networkx as nx

tail = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3]
head = [2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]
ed_ls = [(t, h) for t, h in zip(tail, head)]
G = nx.OrderedDiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(ed_ls)

print(list(G.predecessors(5)))
# Output: [4, 2, 3]
```

**Update**

The reason why even `G.neighbors[4]` return an empty returns an empty result is because in case of DiGraphs, `DiGraph.neighbors` and `DiGraph.successors` are same. You can see from the source code [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/87d13e1869d2b3af7ac7d0cdb065044a658e5330/networkx/classes/digraph.py#L803). As there is no successor for a terminal node, hence we get an empty list.

Comment: Thank you . But it's not clear to me why even G.neighbors(4) doesn't work. The documentation shows it works for Digraph. Could you please clarify why all these look for only the outgoing edge?